# convert numpy matrix into pyspark rdd

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a 2d numpy array.  How do I create a pyspark rdd from that where each row in the matrix is an entry in the rdd?

Such that:

```
rddData.take(1)[0] == list(aaData[0])
```

where `aaData` is the numpy 2d array (matrix) and `rddData` is the rdd created from `aaData`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just `parallelize` it:

```
mat = np.arange(100).reshape(10, -1)
rdd = sc.parallelize(mat)

np.all(rdd.first() == mat[0])
## True
```